# How to create a dataframe from an RDD using Spark Core?

Tags: python, csv

I am new using Spark Core and I need to read a csv file, delete the header and after that convert to RDD and to dataframe.

I tried this, but I cant get a dataframe:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Pruebas").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

file = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/PECE.csv")

def f(idx, iter):
    output = []
    for sublist in iter:
        output.append(sublist)
    if idx > 0:
        return (output)
    else:
        return (output[1:])


def p(x): print(x)

#Utilizamos la funcion para quitar la cabecera
data = file.map(lambda x : x.replace("\"","").split(";")).mapPartitionsWithIndex(f)

print(data)

file2 = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/PECM.csv")

def f2(idx2, iter2):
    output2 = []
    for sublist2 in iter2:
        output2.append(sublist2)
    if idx2 > 0:
        return (output2)
    else:
        return (output2[1:])


def p(x2): print(x2)

data2 = file2.map(lambda x : x2.replace("\"","").split(";")).mapPartitionsWithIndex(f2)

print(data2)

val dataFrame = spark.read.csv("PECM.csv")
```

Comment: I'd rather ask this question in StackOverflow as there is not a clear geospatial component to it.